# XSL file handling through javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i want to handle my xsl file through my javascript code. I made my XSL file but i want to dynamically change my XSL file at run time.As in add more attributes in header or data.
My javascript code as follow`

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
```

`My XSL file code:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th align="left">Title</th>
      <th align="left">Artist</th>
      <th align="left">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="country" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`

Comment: Your XSL document is loaded as an XML document, so you can make changes to it (insert nodes etc) as required. Easier might be to stringify it first and make changes to it as a string (depending on how comfortable with REGEX you are) then convert it back to XML before feeding it to the XSL processor.

Comment: This is *not* an XSLT question -- just an XML question. Any XSLT stylesheet is a well-formed XML document. You can load it as you load any other XML document and you can change any node (or addd or delete nodes) using the available XML-DOM methods. You can see how such manipulations are done in the (source code of) the XPath Visualizer: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html